# How do I create overridable templates?

Tags: 7, theming

I have a module and a theme with different names. The module implements hook_theme() to specify a group of templates with 'template' and 'variables' for each. Template files in the module are working as intended.

In my *theme*, I implement templates/html.tpl.php and templates/page.tpl.php - which both work. But, theme/templates/mytemplate.tpl.php is not overriding the module's template. I have cleared the cache.

What do I have to do so that templates in my theme's templates/ folder will override my own module's templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in [this comment](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_theme/6#comment-12254). For Drupal to find the theme's template overrides, I had to change my theme keys to underscore versions of my dashed template names.

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
{
  return array(

    'my_theme_key' => array(
      'template' => 'my-theme-key',
      'variables' => array(
        ...
      ),
    )
  );
}
```